# What kind of statistical analysis should I do to aggregate these values?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I'm trying to make sense of some data and get statistical results on them.

What I have is the following:

```
Subject    TimeOfDay    Test1    Test2    Test3
A          10:00        valA1    valA2    valA3
B          10:00        valB1    valB2    valB3
C          15:00        valC1    valC2    valC3
D          15:00        valD1    valD2    valD3
```

I'm trying to see if there's a significant difference between test notes (which have a normal distribution) at 10:00 and 15:00.
My problem is that I only have a few subjects for each time of day (3 or 4 in reality).

The good thing is here that **I expect test notes to be correlated**.

My questions are:

- How should I test for these correlations? I guess that I can use the whole population for that, and I was thinking of a standard pearson correlation coefficient and test
- Since I expect these values correlated (and all drawn from a normal distribution), can I just consider each of them as a different subject, same test:

For example:

```
Subject    TimeOfDay    Test
A1         10:00        valA1
A2         10:00        valA2
A3         10:00        valA3
B1         10:00        valB1
B2         10:00        valB2
B3         10:00        valB3
C1         15:00        valC1
C2         15:00        valC2
C3         15:00        valC3
D1         15:00        valD1
D2         15:00        valD2
D3         15:00        valD3
```

If yes, what kind of test should I do to make sure that what I have done is valid? Or do you see a better way to get the same result (more significant performances results between these times) with another method than this one I've  thought of?

A lot for your thoughts!

Comment: How many tests do you have in total, what is the measurement (grading) technique, and are you certain that the 'same test, different subject' option is viable given the nature of your test data?

Comment: I would have 4 tests for example, and 3 subjects per time of day. Tests notes are normal (test result given as a stdev), and these tests are supposed to be quite equivalents (testing the same thing, reading performance for example, even though they aren't obviously identicals.

Comment: It sounds like a simple random intercept model would answer both of your questions. It will give you a intra-subject correlation coefficient and allow you to test the difference in test score across times with a standard error that has been adjusted for the within-subject correlation. Especially because you expect test forms to be positively correlated, you should not just compare the mean of time 10:00 to the mean of 15:00 because your p-value will be too small. Try searching for "random intercept" or "random effect" -- there are lots of examples worked out for R.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have three or four people, then the right test is IOTT - the inter-ocular trauma test.  That is, it hits you between the eyes.  To allow the data to hit you properly, I would recommend graphics.  In particular, I'd put time on the x-axis, score on the y-axis, and put lines for each person.

Comment: I would recommend the same thing at such low sample size. It might not be entirely rational, but I just disregard almost any statistical test running on less than 30 observations.